# How to read a TCP message without knowing its size in Rust?

Tags: rust, redis

I am trying to implement a subset of Redis in Rust.

I successfully wrote code that listens on a TCP connection and parses an incoming Redis RESP message.

But Redis can process multiple messages sent in the same request.

The problem is I don't know how many messages will be sent, and unlike HTTP, the content size of the entire request isn't sent, so reading from the buffer always blocks when there's no more data to be sent.

So how can I implement this?

I thought about maybe reading into a buffer of a specified size, but the problem is that Redis has a max limit of 512 MBs, and I think trying to read 512 MBs in every request will hurt the performance.

Comment: "so reading from the buffer always blocks when there's no more data to be sent." only in blocking mode, you can always [`set_nonblocking`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.set_nonblocking)

Comment: "trying to read 512 MBs in every request will hurt the performance." Yes, but you do realize that you can resize buffers? Or chain them, i.e. keep a linked list of buffers? So you start with small buffer and resize/extend it on demand. Also, I don't really understand your remark about content size. You have to keep reading from socket until you reach `\r`, what content size got to do with anything? It sounds like your current solution is not correct. Btw, content size in HTTP is not mandatory, and at least headers have to be read and parsed almost the same way. Well, prior to HTTP 2 anyway.

Comment: @freakish Every line in a Redis RESP message ends with "\r\n".

I can read the first line to know how many lines the first message contains.

But the message ends with "\r\n". How am I supposed to know that there's more?
If I read another line and there isn't another message, it will block.

Comment: @AdhamSalama if you read, say array data type, then the first line tells you how many elements the array contains. So you need a for loop. And yes, the rest of the message may arrive later, and the call may block. As I said, you have to keep buffering it until you read all. You know that there's going to be more, because that's how RESP is designed.

Comment: @freakish

I am talking about pipelining multiple commands in the same request.


It will keep reading until there's no more data and then it will block indefinitely.

Comment: @AdhamSalama pipelining does not have any special semantics in RESP: its just a stream of commands. And yes, it will block when there are no more commands. What else should happen? You have to handle command by command, not "read all commands" which is meaningless.

Comment: I think your confusion comes from the word "request". There is no such thing in Redis. It is not the case that multiple commands are wrapped into some request. RESP is just a stream of commands: command after command after command, and so on. Pipelining simply means that client can send multiple commands and then wait for responses. This is unlike some classical protocols which require client to wait for response after each request, e.g. some old HTTP versions, prior to 1.1 I think.

Comment: If you've implemented the RESP framing properly there should be no issue here. Each command arrives in sequence over the stream. You should never, ever have to parse the whole buffer, nor should you need a buffer that large. Why not accumulate incomplete commands as they come in, then parse when you receive the right framing? This is how most parsers work, especially inside the Tokio world.

Comment: Worth noting that TCP here is basically irrelevant. It's better to talk about "streaming data", which can be TCP, or could also be a UNIX streaming socket, both of which need similar handling. The transport method is just incidental.

Comment: I seem to have confused you so let me try to explain again.

My original implementation accepts an incoming stream.

The stream has a RESP message that sets a certain to a certain value.

An example:

"*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n"

This is a single command. I know how to handle this. I read the first line "*3" and see that the command consists of 3 lines so I use buffer.read_line 6 times (3*2 because each line specifies the size of the following line).

This is working.

My problem is that in the case of pipelining, the client sends more than 1 command.

Comment: An example:

"*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n*3\r\n$3\r\nSET\r\n$3\r\nanotherkey\r\n$5\r\nanothervalue\r\n"

In this case, I don't know how many commands I am supposed to parse.

I can parse the first one, but If I try to parse again and the stream doesn't contain any more messages, it will block indefinitely.

I can parse all commands, but the last one will always block because I use buffer.read_line one more time but I already parsed everything.

Comment: There is no distinction between, client still plans on sending data but it takes some time to do so and client doesn't send any more data ever *unless* it tells you so by closing the connection, it will only do so when you've processed all it's requests so just receive a message, handle it, repeat until the client closes the connection, if you want a fail-safe in case the client crashes or similar, set a [`read_timeout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.read_timeout) or use non-blocking and handle that case yourself somehow.

Comment: @cafce25
But the Redis docs say that the server accepts multiple messages then sends all the responses.
The example:
Client: INCR X
Client: INCR X
Client: INCR X
Client: INCR X
Server: 1
Server: 2
Server: 3
Server: 4

Comment: @AdhamSalama it's claiming no such thing, it says you can send multiple messages without reading and then read all responses at once, but in fact if you try to read earlier the redis server is quite happy to give you all the responses to all complete requests sent so far.

Comment: @AdhamSalama Pipelining is all about the client, it allows it to send multiple messages and then wait for responses. From servers perspective it is still request response, request response, request response.

Comment: Alright, so I managed to do it. I can handle multiple connections and multiple commands.

The problem is that I can only handle a number of connections equal to the number of threads in the threadpool.

If I set a timeout then some connections are dropped when I run redis-benchmarks.

Would this be solved by using non-blocking mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't.
In any case here's my Redis implementation in case anyone is interested.
https://github.com/adhamsalama/sider